# Why does it seems momentum is transfer fully in Newton cradle?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, momentum, conservation-laws

Let's imagine a 2 balls version of Newton cradle, I raised one of the balls and let go. It will swing down and comes into contact with the other ball which is at rest and I would expect both balls to swing away from each other upon impact according to Newton's third law but somehow only 1 ball is moving at any moment so what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newton's cradle devices invariably contain objects (typically ball bearings) that are almost perfectly elastic.  Due to this, kinetic energy is practically conserved when one ball collides with another ball.  Because momentum is always conserved, you have a situation whereby kinetic energy and momentum must be conserved at the same time.  The only way for this to happen is for one ball to come to rest when it collides with the second ball, while the second ball gains all of the momentum and kinetic energy that the first ball lost.

Answer (score 1):

During the collision Newton's 3rd law still applies.

Lets imagine that ball 1 swings down and collides with ball 2, which is initially at rest.  Ball 1 applies a push force to ball 2, causing ball 2 to accelerate.  When contact ends, ball 2 is moving and swings up.

By Newton's 3rd law ball 2 must also apply a force to ball 1.  That force causes ball 1 to accelerate.  The force from ball 2 opposes ball 1's initial motion, so ball 1 slows down, eventually coming to rest.

From the forces alone, it's hard to see why ball 1 stops completely.  The analysis with energy and momentum described by @David White in his answer is a better way to see that fact.

Answer (score 1):

Let the moving ball have a mass of $m$ and an initial velocity of $+u \hat i$.

After collision you want the balls to go in opposite directions with velocities $+V\hat i$ and $-v\hat i$

Momentum conservation tells you that $m(+V \hat i) + m (-v\hat i) = m(+u\hat i)$

Thus $V > u$ and so $\frac 12 mV^2 > \frac 12 m u^2$ ie the system now has more kinetic energy after the collision than it had before the collision!

A way for this not to happen is to make $v=0$ and then $V=u \Rightarrow$ Newton's cradle.